# Spring Webflux and non-blocking logging with log4j2

Tags: logging, log4j2, spring-webflux

It is well known fact we should not block in a Spring Webflux applications.

In the SpringOne conferences (2020 and 2020), as well as other conferences, several presenters emphasized the importance of having non-blocking **logging** as well.
The argument is: the business logic inside the Webflux can be non-blocking, but if the logging made is blocking, then, it is blocking.

It is easy to test if the business logic layer is non-blocking, using tools such as Blockhound etc...

However, how to ensure the logging part is also not blocking? Any tools? Recommendations?
Do you guys have any example with **log4j2**?
As sample with the pom, the configuration, the log4j2.xml will be great.

Thank you

Comment: log4j2 has async logging support. does that fulfill your requirements?

Comment: Hello Martin, do you have a sample with the pom, like if there is any need for extra dependencies we need to bring, such as the disruptor jar?

And what would be the configuration needed in the log4j2 file? Any -D parameter needed?

Comment: you can check the official log4j documentation: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Martin suggested is correct. Following the doc, the use of `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector` will be a solution.

I am also seeing references to LMAX disruptor.

Tried a combination of both and BlockHound tested, nothing blocking.